# Oracle How to populate data when there is no query record

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to execute the following SQL  in PL/SQL

```
select did, n1,  n2 ,n3  
from t where t.did in (‘A’,’C’,’G’)
```

the result  will be  “no recode”

[image]

I wish  the result can be like this

[image]

how should I write the sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should have some other table which maintains all possible `did` values.  In absence of that, we can try using a CTE here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 'A' AS did FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C' FROM dual
)

SELECT
    t1.did,
    t2.n1,
    t2.n2,
    t3.n3
FROM cte t1
LEFT JOIN t t2
    ON t1.did = t2.did;
```

Of course, this also means that should your table have *more* than one record matching a giving `did` value, that your result set would also have more than one record for that `did` value.  If you always expect a single record per `did` value, then you would have to give us the logic behind that.